# Testing angularj facebook login directive

Tags: facebook, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I am creating a Facebook login directive based off this [blog](http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2013/04/facebook-login-with-javascript-sdk.html).

```js
  app.directive('facebook', function($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      controller: function($scope, $attrs, $location) {
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
          var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
          ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
    // ... the rest of the directive
```

How can I unit test this anonymous function? Mocking the document doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are loading the facebook sdk asynchronously, you are basically out of luck. Really the question you should ask yourself is "What do I want to test?" If that question is "log into facebook" then really you should use an integration test runner.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing

Comment: I don't want to hit facebook in my unit tests. Also, the rest of this class needs to be tested.